# Gluing two strongly convex function

Tags: analysis, optimization, convex-analysis

Definition: We call $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a $\lambda$-strongly convex function iff for every $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $t\in[0,1]$ it follows
$$f(tx+(1−t)y)\leq tf(x)+(1−t)f(y)−λt(1−t)\|x−y\|^2,$$
where $\lambda>0$.

Let $f$ be a $C^2$-$λ$-strongly convex function and $g$ be a $C^2$-$μ$-strongly convex function. Is there a $C^2$-$ν$-strongly convex function $h$ such that $h(x)=f(x)$ in a ball of zero and $h(x)=g(x)$ in a neighborhood of infinity?

Comment: What's $\nu$????

Comment: A parameter $\nu>0$.